# Using filter argument in test_package to skip tests

Tags: regex, r, cran, testthat

I would like to run my package unit tests during `R CMD check`, but skip tests that require an internet connection. By convention, all unit tests that require internet have the word `network` in their filename.

Hence my `run-all.R` contains:

```
library(testthat)
test_package("mypackage", filter="^((?!network).)*$")
```

However this gives an `invalid regular expression` error. How do I specify the `filter` argument such that it runs each unit test except the ones with the word `network` in them?

Comment: I didn't (thanks) but I really don't want `CMD check` depend on external servers (not just connectivity)

Comment: And do you know about the `NOT_CRAN` envvar?

Comment: That only works within `devtools` right?

Comment: Yes but you can also set up yourself. I don't think you can express what you want without a negative look ahead assertion which only the perl engine supports.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `invert` argument:

```
test_package("mypackage", filter="network", invert=TRUE)
```

The `invert` argument eventually gets forwarded to `grepl` via the `...` argument via `test_check` -> `run_tests` -> `test_dir` -> etc.  From `?test_dir`:

> ...: Additional arguments passed to 'grepl' to control filtering.