# testthat pattern for long-running tests

Tags: r, cran, testthat

I have a bunch of tests that I don't want them running during CRAN checks or Travis CI builds.  They are either long-running, or they could cause transaction/concurrency conflicts writing to a networked database.  What approach of separating them (from the R CMD check tests) works best with [testthat](https://github.com/hadley/testthat)?

Should I put those tests in a separate folder?  Should I tag their filename and use a regex? (eg [Using filter argument in test_package to skip tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675252/using-filter-argument-in-test-package-to-skip-tests) by @Jeroen)

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html:

> Long-running tests and vignette code can be made optional for
>   checking, but do ensure that the checks that are left do exercise all
>   the features of the package.

Comment: If you put them in another directory within tests, then you can still test them manually with `test_dir()`, but they won't be running with `test()` or `R CMD check`. E.g. R6 has some manual tests: https://github.com/wch/R6/tree/master/tests

Comment: I like that @GaborCsardi, and how the tests are contained together, but distinguished by `test()` and `test_dir()`.

Comment: @GaborCsardi that was exactly what I was looking for, and it [worked well](https://github.com/OuhscBbmc/REDCapR/commit/a93bf9e95c259068ba740596679f3943e7b521fa) for my package's needs.  If you change your comment to an answer, I'd like to give your response credit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you put them in another directory within `tests`, then you can still test them manually with `test_dir()`, but they won't be running with `test()` or `R CMD check`.

E.g. R6 has some manual tests: https://github.com/wch/R6/tree/master/tests

Answer (score 8):

FYI: `testthat` 0.9 now comes with a `skip()` function.

However, I can't seem to figure out how/where exactly to use it. Putting inside my `test_that()` function, the test runs anyway. If you put it before `testthat()`, then `skip()` throws an error.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that --I saw the release announcement a few days ago.  Immediately inside the test functions, I've added the like `testthat::skip_on_cran()`.

It's a good fit for some of my tests, because the main reason I wanted some manual tests are so that it wouldn't get rejected from CRAN if the server wasn't peppy right then.  I don't really care if the Travis-CI or R-Forge checks fail, because it's easy to rerun.

Comment: Could you tell me, how exactly you are using `skip()` and/or `skip_on_cran()`? Where do I need to put it in order to make a specific test skip when running `test_package()` or `CRTL+SHFT+T` in RStudio?

Comment: Here is a link to the [test code](https://github.com/OuhscBbmc/REDCapR/blob/80e9fad0eb8a42375d1291360032c4ee5ec12b97/tests/testthat/test-read_oneshot.R#L10).

To run it, I either check the package with `CTRL+SHIFT+E` or run just the tests with [`test_results_checked <- devtools::test()`](https://github.com/OuhscBbmc/REDCapR/blob/80e9fad0eb8a42375d1291360032c4ee5ec12b97/utility_scripts/refresh.R#L12).

Comment: Thanks man. That's how I did it and it didn't work for some reason but now it does ;-) Must have been something else

Comment: Note that skip (At least in current dev version) requires a message argument. E.g. inside `test_that(` use `if (is.friday(today())) skip("Not today.")`