# Handling Test Workflows in R testthat

Tags: r, testing, workflow, testthat

I've two files `test_utils.r` and `test_core.r`, they contain tests for various utilities and some core functions separated into different 'context'. I can control the flow of tests within each file by moving around my `test_that()` statements.

But am looking for a way in which I can create different workflows, say ensuring that at run time, tests from Context A_utils runs first followed by tests from Context B_Core followed by context B_Utils.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

BrajeshS,

1. I have an idea. Have you tried the *skip()* function in version 0.9 or better? See [testthat](/questions/tagged/testthat) [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/testthat/testthat.pdf) on page 7:

   > Description
   >
   > This function allows you to skip a test if it’s not currently available.
   >    This will produce an informative message, but will not cause the test suite
   >    to fail.

   It was introduced to skip tests if an internet connection or API not available. You could then dependent on your workflow, jump over tests.
2. To see example code using skip_on_cran, look at wibeasley's answer where he provides test code in Rappster's reply - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26068397/4606130

I am still getting to grips with testthat. Hope this helps you.