# Datetime formatting in R3.0.3 and R3.1.3

Tags: r, datetime, strftime, cran

I have a package on CRAN called UNF, which creates a hash of a `data.frame` (for use in data citation). I have some tests in the package related to the formatting of datetimes (I'm using testthat). They work correctly on the current version of R (3.1.3), but once I submitted to CRAN, [one of these tests fail on "r-oldrel-windows" (3.0.3)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_UNF.html).

I've tracked down the difference to the following code, which yields different results in the two versions of R. Here's the correct output (from 3.1.3):

```
x = strptime("2014-08-22T16:51:05Z", "%FT%H:%M:%OSZ", tz="UTC")
x
# [1] "2014-08-22 16:51:05 UTC"
strftime(x, "%F")
# [1] "2014-08-22"
```

And here's the output from 3.0.3:

```
x = strptime("2014-08-22T16:51:05Z", "%FT%H:%M:%OSZ", tz="UTC")
x
# [1] "2014-08-22 16:51:05 UTC"
strftime(x, "%F")
# [1] ""
```

As you can see, the output of `strftime` is an empty character string rather than an ISO 8601 formatted date. Any idea what the change was between these two versions? And how can I correct this? Or, how can I avoid having the tests fail on CRAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that %F was not an option in earlier versions of R. So the base code is ignoring the string so it formats as empty string. I tried using a letter not in the current help and it returns a string with that letter not a date.

Thomas, there is a `skip()` function in testthat and skip_on_CRAN functionality.

1. Take a look at help

   ```
   ?testthat::skip_on_cran
   ```
2. *wbeasley* has [some test code](https://github.com/OuhscBbmc/REDCapR/blob/80e9fad0eb8a42375d1291360032c4ee5ec12b97/tests/testthat/test-read_oneshot.R#L10) which may assist you. (See his helpful comments in this answer to Rappster in [25595487](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595487/testthat-pattern-for-long-running-tests)). You will see how he puts this skip command inside the testthat functions brackets. Paraphrasing it below:

   ```
   library(testthat)        

   testthat("example"),{
     testthat::skip_on_cran()
     # test code below
     x <-2
     expect_equal(x,2)
   })
   ```
3. It might be an OS thing with Windows. Doing some more digging revealed this - Take a look at this describing R 3.0.2. http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/strftime

   The docs warn of some issues with some % flags in Windows. Quoting (my bold):

> Also defined in the current standards but less widely implemented (e.g. **not for output on Windows**) are
>
> %C Century (00--99): the integer part of the year divided by 100.
>
> ...
>
> %F Equivalent to %Y-%m-%d (the ISO 8601 date format).
>
> ...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yup, that was it. `%F` was not previously supported as an output format on Windows. Thanks!